# Disabling local host ipmitool access

Tags: linux, ipmi, ipmitool

On servers from most/many vendors, I am able to see potentially sensitive information using commands like:

```
ipmitool user list 1
```

or

```
ipmitool lan print 1
```

Or set new administrator users, all of which does not require authentication.

This is not necessarily something you would want if you give other users bare metal access. Is there a way to prevent a local host user from accessing/modifying the BMC settings?

Comment: By "local user" do you mean a local user on the OS that is installed on the machine with the IPMI?

Answer (score 0):

Disable OS level or "local" IMPI access, via the vendor-specific procedure for your BMC.

ipmitool and the devices it uses are generally restricted to privilaged OS users. root can get around [kernel module blocking](https://serverfault.com/questions/592278/preventing-ipmi-kernel-drivers-from-loading) or install missing ipmi software.

Answer (score 0):

As @John pointed out. Disabling OS level or "local" IPMI access is a good start. Doing so depends on the vendor of the IPMI device. Also ensuring that `IPMItools` is not installed on the OS running on the machine with IPMI is also a good option.

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/570010/dedicated-servers-how-to-protect-ipmi) is a similar thread for securing IPMI.

SuperMicro also has some [decent documentation](https://www.supermicro.com/products/nfo/files/IPMI/Best_Practices_BMC_Security.pdf) on the topic as well.
It mostly boils down to:

- Restrict inbound traffic
- Use dedicated management interfaces for utilizing IPMI/BMCs.
- Change defaults on the IPMI.
- Monitor traffic between IPMIs/BMCs from other portions of your network.